# PHP class setName function

Tags: php

I am trying to make a basic class that stores a name string variable. The problem is that the setName function is not working properly for me. I am getting the error:

Catchable fatal error: Method TesterClass::__toString() must return a string value in C:\xampp\htdocs\CA18\testerPage.php on line 12

I have tried many different ways of doing this, but nothing seems to fix it: The code is as follows:

```html
<?php 
 class TesterClass
 {
  public $name;
  
  public function setName($n)
  {
   $name = $n;
  }
  public function __toString()
  {
   return $this->name;
  }
  public function __construct()
  {
   $numArgs = func_num_args();
   $args = func_get_args();
   if ($numArgs == 0)
   {
    setName($args[0]);
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

Here is the class implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Payroll</title>   
    </head> 
    <body>
  <h1>Payroll</h1>
  <?php
   require "TesterClass.php";
   $myObject = new TesterClass("Philllip");
   echo $myObject;
  ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $this->name = $n in setName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
public function setName($n)
        {
            $this->$name = $n;
        }
```

`$this` represents any instance of the class(`$myObject` in your case) while `$name` alone is a new variable.

I think your check also is wrong.

```
 public function __construct()
            {
                $numArgs = func_num_args();
                $args = func_get_args();
                if ($numArgs == 0)//This condition says that there are no args passed so it should give an error
                {
                    //no args
                } 
                else $this->setName($args[0]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `setName()` you are setting it to a local variable `$name` not the `$name` variable in the class ... you need to use `$this->name`. You also need to reference `$this->setName()` and when you check for the number of args, you are looking for when there are 0 ... you should be looking for when there are more than 0.

```
class TesterClass
{
    public $name;

    public function setName($n)
    {
        $this->name = $n;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $numArgs = func_num_args();
        $args = func_get_args();
        if ($numArgs)
        {
            $this->setName($args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I changed that and I am still seeing the same error

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, there also needs to be a $this-> before the setName() function call. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class TesterClass
{
    public $name = ''; // make sure this is a string!

    public function setName($n)
    {
        $this->name = $n;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $numArgs = func_num_args();
        $args = func_get_args();
        if (count($numArgs)) // if there is an arg!
        {
            $this->setName($args[0]); // class methods are called with $this!
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know why you are using `func_get_args`, but you could also just use a named parameter, with a default value.

```
    public function __construct($name = '')
    {
        $this->setName($name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
public function setName($n)
{
    $name = $n;
}
```

But it should be

```
public function setName($n)
{
    $this->name = $n;
}
```

In the first code, you are setting a local scope variable named "name" in setName function.
In the last code, you are setting the object property named "name".

Also you should check if it is a valid string value, AND, your property should have an string default value. Otherwise, you may get same error if you did not set name and try to get name.